# Meaning of symbols after the bar in probability notation

Tags: probability, machine-learning

I am taking Andrew Ng's machine learning course on Coursera where, in the discussion of logistic regression, we say that a given hypothesis function returns:

> $P(y=1|x;Θ)$

This is described as "the probability that y=1, given x and parameterized by Θ."

As background for those who don't know, the hypothesis function will look something like:

> $h(x) = Θ^\top X = Θ_1 x_1 + Θ_2 x_2 + Θ_3 x_3$

(I mean the integers in the above equation to be subscripts but I don't know how to write them.) [edit: place mathjax delimiters around the equation, and use underscore to mark up subscript.]

With all that said, my questions are:

1. Why is that additional notation after the bar helpful? Why not just say $P(y=1)$? Is it because we might have different equations for assessing $P(y=1)$ and would need to distinguish between them, like $P(y=1|y;z)$?
2. Why do we say "given x" but "parameterized by theta"? Is there a difference? If I had to guess it would be that "parameterization" is how we choose coefficients for an equation before we are ready to use it (such as in our gradient descent / other fitting step) and we then say "given x" because it is a free variable and we're choosing a particular value. But I'm not sure if that's right.

Comment: I think you have guessed the meaning of the notation and the distinction between "parameterized" and "given" pretty well. I also think the assumption is that you actually have some fixed underlying probability distribution described by some particular list of numbers $\Theta,$ but either we don't know what it is (we're trying to learn it) or we want to be able to apply the solution to more than just one set of numbers.

Comment: @Graham Kemp thanks for the edit assistance. I also found the following MathJax tutorial which is super helpful. I'll refer to it in the future: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

When we write $~\mathsf P(y=1\mid x; \Theta)~$ we mean "the conditional probability of $y$ realising value $1$ when given $x$, using parameter $\Theta$."

The $x$ is a random variable, to which $y$ is dependent.   As such, the conditional probability function of $y$ given $x$ will differ from the marginal probability function of $y$.

The $\Theta$ is a parameter of the distribution.   It is not random.   It has a fixed value; we just *may* not know what it is.   So we treat the parameter as an argument of the probability function rather than a global constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you describe what you mean by "conditional probability function" vs "marginal probability function"?

I still have the broader question of why it's actually helpful to include $x;\theta$ in the notation, instead of just writing $P(y=1)$ which would be a bit simpler.

Comment: I've seen the same thing when we write the hypothesis function as $h_\theta (X)$ instead of just $h(x)$ when the latter seems like all that would be required.

I guess my question is: Are these actually *necessary* in practice to distinguish from other functions, or are they generally ornamental?

Comment: It distinguishes $h_{0.1}(x)$ from $h_{0.9}(x)$.  @Stephen